# Is the Elan Resilience, Enhanced feat unbalanced?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, races

I don't believe Elan Resilience is unbalanced due to this Jeremy Smith (Dreamscarred Press) quote:

> Actually, resilience has no limit. It is not a power, it's a supernatural ability, and thus not subject to the manifester level cap.
>
> That being said, it is a highly inefficient way to do it and you can only do it once in a round. You can only really do something like that if you're a primary manifester, since psychic warriors, etc have very lower power point pools.
>
> 10 power points = 50 temporary hit points = 20 blocked damage.
>
> Personally, I'd rather have the 50 temporary hit points.
>
> That being said, blowing 30 pp to block 60 damage - if you don't mind spending 10% (or more) of your daily resources in a single swift action... more power to you.

So, can the same be said about the Elan Resilience, Enhanced feat?

> **Prerequisite:** Elan.
>
> **Benefit:** As an immediate action, you can reduce the damage you are about to take by 4 points for every 1 power point spent.
>
> **Normal:** A typical elan can reduce damage he is about to take by 2 points for every 1 power point spent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Not at all.

While you can as an immediate reaction reduce damage that could otherwise knock you out or outright kill you to the point you can keep standing, the cost isn't exactly cheap. The power [Vigor](http://dndsrd.net/psionicPowersQtoW.html#vigor) gives you 5 temporary HP for each power point spent as a standard action and duration of 1min/level.

The real value of Enhanced Elan Resilience is the immediate action activation to save you one really bad situation once per turn. Unless you're a manifester, you won't have PP enough to use it more than once or twice and a feat for 8 of damage mitigation per day is a terrible choice, even more since you already would have 4. If you're a manifester you have access to other methods to keep yourself safe that won't cost you a feat but with the possibility to burn your reserves once in a while as an immediate action to stay alive is still useful.

The feat isn't broken or really good, but isn't the worst either.

Comment: One player thought it as cheap, the other didn't. The player who used it said, "Think of it like, I'm using my "spell slots" to save my life!" This seemed to ameliorate the issue a bit.

Comment: @Caldrun It's a nice and reasonable way to see it.